# Changing the skin of a player

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a game where the skin of my player would change in a particular scene only.

First, I've got a movieClip with frame names for specific character states. So when the code wants the character to look like it's walking it goes to the frame named "walk". The code goes like this :

```
public function startWalking(inputX:Number, inputY:Number):void{
        targetX = inputX;
        targetY = inputY;

        getIncrements(targetX, targetY);

        gotoAndStop("walk");
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, walk, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener("reachedPoint", stopWalking, false, 0, true);
        dispatchEvent(new Event("playerWalking"));
```

Same thing for the standing position with a frame "default".

In order to change the skin of my player in a particular scene, I added a whole new frame for each of these states that is the name of the state plus the skin name, and I've created a set of animations that represent the new skin:
Using "walk" as an example:
Basic frame name: "walk"
Car skin frame name: "walkcar"

So, I've added a String variable called something like "skinValue":

```
public var skinValue:String;
```

And then in code I change the code from:

```
gotoAndStop("walk")
```

to:

```
gotoAndStop("walk"+skinValue)
```

I want to set the "skinValue" to "car", in this way the code "walk"+skinValue would evaluate to "walkcar" and it would go to the car frame.

But, I've got a problem with setting "skinValue"... And I really can't figure out how to define it properly...
If someone could help, it'll be awesome.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to a new scene, then you will get a key, like "car".

Your role movieclip will provider a function like

```
public function goToScene(sceneKey:String):void {
     gotoAndStop("walk" + sceneKey)
}
```

Comment: Still the same error as I have since 2 weeks.. :Error #2109: Frame label defaultnull not found in scene defaultnull.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()

Comment: Have you debugged what the frame labels in you role mc?

Comment: yes. Here's what I got : Creating new background: wind                   
null
defaultnull

Comment: Where is walk label and walkcar label? Do your walk label work before you use walkcar?