# Character, CPU and Skin Selection in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, button, flash

I have created the character selection for a player, CPU and skin to choose and select. Once I select one of the character, CPU or the skin, the character will change, when the game is selected. The code filled with array and boolean in the message text.

Here's my code,

For Character Selection:

```
var Minami_selected: Boolean = false;
var Peach_selected: Boolean = false;
var Daisy_selected: Boolean = false;
var Haurka_selected: Boolean = false;
var Kirara_selected: Boolean = false;
var Towa_selected: Boolean = false;
var SwimsuitRoll_selected: Boolean = false;
var Yui_selected: Boolean = false;
var IrisAnother_selected: Boolean = false;

Minami_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, minamiSelected);
function minamiSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Minami_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Kaido Minami";
}

Yui_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yuiSelected);
function yuiSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Yui_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Nanase Yui";
}

Peach_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, peachSelected);
function peachSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Peach_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Princess Peach";
}

Kirara_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kiraraSelected);
function kiraraSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Kirara_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Amanogawa Kirara";
}

Haurka_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, haurkaSelected);
function haurkaSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Haurka_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Haurno Haurka";
}

Towa_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, towaSelected);
function towaSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Towa_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Agaki Towa";
}

Daisy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, daisySelected);
function daisySelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Daisy_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Princess Daisy";
}

IrisAnother_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, irisAnotherSelected);
function irisAnotherSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    IrisAnother_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Iris -Another-";
}

SwimsuitRoll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swimsuitRollSelected);
function swimsuitRollSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    SwimsuitRoll_selected = true;
    message_txt.text = "Swimsuit Roll";
}
```

For CPU:

```
var Minami_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var Peach_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var Daisy_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var Haurka_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var Kirara_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var Towa_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var SwimsuitRoll_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var Yui_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;
var IrisAnother_CPUSelected: Boolean = false;

Minami_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, minamiCPUSelected);
function minamiCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Minami_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Kaido Minami";
}

Yui_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yuiCPUSelected);
function yuiCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Yui_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Nanase Yui";
}

Peach_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, peachCPUSelected);
function peachCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Peach_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Princess Peach";
}

Kirara_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kiraraCPUSelected);
function kiraraCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Kirara_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Amanogawa Kirara";
}

Haurka_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, haurkaCPUSelected);
function haurkaCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Haurka_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Haurno Haurka";
}

Towa_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, towaCPUSelected);
function towaCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Towa_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Agaki Towa";
}

Daisy_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, daisyCPUSelected);
function daisyCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Daisy_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Princess Daisy";
}

IrisAnother_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, irisAnotherCPUSelected);
function irisAnotherCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    IrisAnother_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Iris -Another-";
}
SwimsuitRoll_selectedCPU_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swimsuitRollCPUSelected);
function swimsuitRollCPUSelected(event: MouseEvent): void {
    SwimsuitRoll_CPUSelected = true;
    characterCPUName_txt.text = "Swimsuit Roll";
}
```

For Skin Selection:

```
var Minami_skinSelected: Boolean = false;
var Peach_skinSelected: Boolean = false;
var Daisy_skinSelected: Boolean = false;
var Haurka_skinSelected: Boolean = false;
var Kirara_skinSelected: Boolean = false;
var Towa_skinSelected: Boolean = false;
var SwimsuitRoll_skinSelected: Boolean = false;
var Yui_skinSelected: Boolean = false;

Minami_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, minamiSkinSelection);
function minamiSkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Minami_skinSelected = true;
    var MinamiSkin: Array = ["One-Piece Swimsuit", "Wetsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * MinamiSkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = "Kaido Minani: " + MinamiSkin[randomNumber].toString();
}

Haurka_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, haurkaSkinSelection);
function haurkaSkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Haurka_skinSelected = true;
    var HaurkaSkin: Array = ["One-Piece Swimsuit", "Two-Piece Swimsuit", "Wetsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * HaurkaSkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = HaurkaSkin[randomNumber].toString();
}

Kirara_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kiraraSkinSelection);
function kiraraSkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Kirara_skinSelected == true;
    var KiraraSkin: Array = ["Beach Swimsuit", "Competitive Swimsuit", "Wetsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * KiraraSkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = KiraraSkin[randomNumber].toString();
}

Towa_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, towaSkinSelection);
function towaSkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Towa_skinSelected == true;
    var TowaSkin: Array = ["One-Piece Swimsuit", "Wetsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * TowaSkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = TowaSkin[randomNumber].toString();
}
Yui_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yuiSkinSelection);
function yuiSkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Yui_skinSelected == true;
    var YuiSkin: Array = ["Beach Swimsuit", "Swim Club Swimsuit", "Competitive Swimsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * YuiSkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = YuiSkin[randomNumber].toString();
}
Peach_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, peachSkinSelection);
function peachSkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Peach_skinSelected = true;
    var PeachSkin: Array = ["Competitive Swimsuit", "Leotard Swimsuit", "Wetsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * PeachSkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = PeachSkin[randomNumber].toString();
}
Daisy_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, daisySkinSelection);
function daisySkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    Daisy_skinSelected == true;
    var DaisySkin: Array = ["Competitive Swimsuit", "Leotard Swimsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * DaisySkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = DaisySkin[randomNumber].toString();
}

SwimsuitRoll_Skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swimsuitRollSkinSelection);
function swimsuitRollSkinSelection(event: MouseEvent): void {
    SwimsuitRoll_skinSelected == true;
    var SwimsuitRollSkin: Array = ["Beach Swimsuit", "School Swimsuit"];
    var randomNumber: int = (Math.random() * SwimsuitRollSkin.length);
    skinName_txt.text = SwimsuitRollSkin[randomNumber].toString();
}
```

For Selected Skin:

```
character.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playerSkin);
function playerSkin(e: Event): void {
    if (Minami_selected == true && Minami_skinSelected == true && MinamiSkin[randomNumber] == 0) {
        character.gotoAndStop("Minami_Wetsuit");
    } else if (Minami_selected == true && Minami_skinSelected == true && MinamiSkin[randomNumber] == 1) {
        character.gotoAndStop("Minami_OnePieceSwimsuit");
    } else if (Minami_selected == true && Minami_skinSelected == true && MinamiSkin[randomNumber] == 2) {
        character.gotoAndStop("Minami_ShortWetsuit");
    } else if (Minami_selected == true) {
        character.gotoAndStop("Minami_Wetsuit");
    }
}
```

The script for selected skin has been added. Any ideas how to change?

```
ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label Minami_Wetsuit not found in scene Minami_Wetsuit.
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at BlowfishPong_fla::MainTimeline/playerSkin()[BlowfishPong_fla.MainTimeline::frame28:266]
```

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPxPibOYdf0

Comment: _"I have created the character selection for a player, CPU and skin to choose and select. Once I select one of the character, CPU or the skin, the character will change,"_ this is **not making sense**... Are you saying, character is sometimes only  "CPU" and character is sometimes only "the skin"...??? In your code you don't have a `character` to change so where should it change? Please [Edit your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72786103/edit) text to **explain better** what you have in front of you (screen objects and code variables) and what needs to happen with it.

Comment: PS: **And** means `A + B` ... **Or** means `choose one: A<-->B` ... You cannot say first _"CPU **and** skin to choose and select"_ then later say _"I select one of the character, CPU **or** the skin"_ ... No-one can help you if they don't understand you!!! Is there 3 things to select (select character, then select skin, then select CPU) ...or Maybe it's just 2 things to select like `character = CPU <- or -> Skin`. Which one are you doing?... You say _"I have created the character selection for a player, CPU and skin to choose and select."_ what does that even mean in English???

Comment: For Skin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652170/changing-the-skin-of-a-player; For Character: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312590/action-script-3-character-selection. Can you check these out?

Comment: For character selection, we choose a character & when it is in skin selection, we choose a skin for a character.

Comment: Hi, you're not telling me **what is the problem to solve**. This question is from 3 months ago. I don't know what you've changed or tried. All I understand is that you select some options and then set the expected boolean to true + some text is updated... So what is the problem? What is the problem if user presses button `Minami_Skin_btn`?

Comment: To Change the Character for the game: for Example, Kirara_selected = true; To change the skin for the same character: for Example, Kirara_selected = true and Kirara_skinSelected == true; There is also an array for more than one skin:  var KiraraSkin: Array = ["Beach Swimsuit", "Competitive Swimsuit", "Wetsuit"];

Comment: I'm using the 'OR'; To choose a character, either change a skin or not.